# C language: Convert Pointer to String, what am I getting back?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm just experimenting with some system level programming using c. 
I have encountered something ambiguous and I'm hoping someone here can clear it up for me.

If I make a char* and then feed the address into a function in the following way

```
char* string;
os_IntToString(&string, string);

void os_IntToString(int value, char* str) {
    int scancode_offset = 48;

    char* start = *str;
    do{
        int piece = value % 10;
        *str++ = piece + scancode_offset;
        value = value / 10;
    } while(value);
    *str-- = '\0';
}
```

Then what exactly am I getting back?
I get real numbers, an example would be 589796. Obviously the address is backwards but what base system is it?

Memory addresses are in hex right? But the function uses Int which is decimal base 10?
Is that correct? Does a conversion process happen or do I now have a deciaml address, I just don't know.

Can anyone clear this up please. Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: You get random locations in storage altered, since you have not set the value of "string".

Comment: `char* start = *str;` doesn't make any sense and should have given you compiler warnings, if you had a decent C compiler.

Comment: `return start;` doesn't make any sense in a void function. It invokes undefined behavior, and will possibly cause your program to crash & burn. A decent C compiler would have given errors/warnings.

Comment: `os_IntToString(&string, string);` as a function prototype doesn't make any sense and will not compile on a C99 compiler.

Comment: @lundin: Well it does compile under GCC so...yeah, also why does it not make sense? What I'm looking to do pass in an adress and print it out as a string for debugging puropses, thus I pass in an address and a char* to hold the results, what doesn't make sense about that?

Comment: char* start = *str; doesn't make any sense.  Again,why not? I am trying to make a copy of the pointerso that as I increment *str I still have a record of where the origin is, I'll need that to reverse the result later. Am I doing that assignment wrong?

Comment: Lundin, is right. You probably mean `char* start = str;`. Note there is no asterisk before `str`. You want to assign the pointer value of `str` but your code __dereferences__ `str` and uses the `char` that it points to. (By the way, you never actually use `start` in your function.)

Comment: so just to spell it out for an idiot like me, If I want to make a pointer which points to the same place as another pointer then I reference the source pointer without an asterix. Got it, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All data (memory addresses, ints, pointers, strings, floats, etc) are internally stored as binary, or base 2.

Being base 10 or base 16 is not a question of how the hardware or software (libc, your program, the assmebly, or even CPU microcode) stores and manipulates it (except for binary-coded decimal which is rarely used except for certain display and conversion steps).

When you are returned an int, while you assume it as base 10(and most calls that will print the int display it as base 10), for the hardware it holds its meaning as  base 2, the same as the pointer or memory address. It just gets printed that way.

Moreover, for the memory address, base 2 is only due to the way the circuits operate in the CPU and northbridge. When you see it as base 16, it's just the debugger's representation. We could hypothetically address it as base 10 and refer to 65536 in memory but it is just easier to use `10000` for display as trailing zeroes help clue the programmer into the alignment. It's just a convenient representation. We could use base 13 and call it  23AA3 but that would simply be inconvenient. When we see it as a number, it is not necessarily a number. It is a location, and while in certain respects it *could* be considered a number, and it is *convenient* for the programmer to see it as a number, the nonlinear nature of memory mapping on today's systems can make that consideration somewhat incorrect.

While there may be problems with the code itself I'm simply answering the point of number representation.

Comment: Memory addresses and pointers are not numbers. They might be stored that way, and they can be *converted* to numbers, but the language standard doesn't describe them as numbers. They're just addresses.

Comment: @KeithThompson As I have seen it, when  an address travels via a control/logic bus from point A to point B on the hardware, it is transmitted as a number that addresses a certain location in memory. Just like on a street 2013 is a number and an address. Semantically (I don't program C/C++ much) it has a somewhat different meaning depending on the level at which one looks at it.

Comment: Are you talking about C semantics or the workings of some particular hardware? A stored floating-point value might be stored as 64 bits, but it doesn't make sense to think of it as a 64-bit *integer* -- nor does it make sense (as far as C semantics are concerned) to think of the stored bits of a pointer value as an integer. The interpretation of those bits is unspecified by the C language.

Comment: I think I've probably made a mistake. my wording probably.

Comment: Um, well what i'm doing is bare metal programming on a 0x86 in protected mode. I'm using bochs to run the code. What i'm basically trying to figure out is if I make 2 pointers in C next to each other then if I put data in the first pointer will the second pointer will it overwrite the contents of the next pointer. The 2 values I get back from that function are 4bytes apart, so I assume the place it points at is a 32bit address, if those 2 addresses are only a double apart will writing to one affect the other?

Comment: @user849912 I'd ask a new question. I would assume so but I'm not totally sure,

Answer (score 3):

As far as the C language is concerned, addresses are not "in hex", nor are they numbers.  Addresses are just addresses, or pointer values.  Depending on the addressing scheme of the system you're using, addresses might be *represented* in hex (for example, if printed with `printf`'s `"%p"` format).  You can also convert an address to an integer, but the result of the conversion is implementation-defined -- and integers aren't "in hex" either, though you can generate a human-readable hexadecimal representation of an integer.  (Integers are represented in binary.)

As for your function, you've defined it with a `void` return type, and then attempted to return a `char*` value from it. You should have gotten *at least* a warning from your compiler, if not a fatal error.

Comment: Of course an address is a number. How that number is represented to the human programmer varies, hex is by far the most common notation. But whenever you try to access an address by handing the CPU some op code that requires an address as parameter, it expects a number.

Comment: @Lundin: Can you cite wording in the C standard that says an address is a number? (Hint: It doesn't say so.) I'm not sure the standard even says what the word "number" means. Consider a segmented implementation, where an address consists of, say, an index into a system descriptor table and an offset; is that a "number"?

Comment: And who cares about the C standard, I'm talking about computers. Can you site a CPU manual that doesn't name an address as a number? Sure there are various paging/banking/extended memory mechanisms, but that doesn't matter. (Especially, they don't matter to beginner programmers, for the sake of pedagogy.) It all boil downs to what instructions the CPU executes. The definition of an address is the thing you feed to the CPU when doing an absolute or indirect access to memory.

Comment: @Lundin: "*And who cares about the C standard*" -- I do, because it's the definition of the C language, which is what this question is explicitly about. There are multiple levels of abstraction. If you're going to restrict yourself to the lowest one, that's fine, but then you might as well program in assembly language. An understanding of the C language applies to *all* systems that support C implementations. Can you explain why you can't add, multiply, or divide two pointer values?

Comment: @Lundin - sure, any of the many processors which do not have a single, linear address space.  Where that is the case, you cannot reduce an address to "a number" because you also have to know which address space applies.

Comment: Also yes the return is a mistake, I originally tried to return the pointer but changed it to just write to the pointer that is passed to the function. I'll remove it to reduce confusion

Comment: Downvoter: I've tweaked the first two sentences. Does that address your concerns?

Comment: @Lundin I'd quit while I was very, very far behind.  Addressing modes don't just boil down to absolute or indirect, most textbooks for high level and low level approaches to memory space treat that space as a block, page, section, etc... and once you understand how that space is laid out you can assign some superficial numerical value that is really only there for the user.  Also, memory mapped hardware, that can be more storage, that goes to various memory indirect modes that still don't directly map to numbers. Finally an address is a set of high and low voltages, just a little fyi.

Comment: @JeffLangemeier As I already mentioned, the various block & page mechanisms don't make a difference, they are numbers as well. An address is not a set of high and low voltages, it is a unique _number_, which can be represented by voltages, or as pixels on the screen. Or do you believe that binary numbers are not numbers? Were it not a number, then it would not be unique. And if it was not, then how would you access a particular memory cell?

Comment: @Lundin: Not all collections of bits are numbers. Pointers do not necessarily share all the properties of numbers, such as the ability to add two of then and get a meaningful result.

Answer (score 1):

The address isn't backwards.  Printf shoudl always print big endian.  If you print the address locations, if you get 589796 when an int, if you print it as hex, then you'll get 0x8FFE4 = 589796.  Everything is working as it should, since no matter hwo you print it, its going to be the correct memory address, just with a different representation.

Comment: Yeah but if you look at my code the conversion to scan codes uses modulus to isolate the last digit of the number recursively, thus they are written into the char* the wrong way round.